# Form of Divisors of Proth numbers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Proth number is a number of the form :

$z⋅2^k+1$
where z is an odd positive integer and k is a positive integer such that : $2^k>z$

Is there a form for divisors of Proth Numbers? (Like Mersenne and Fermat Numbers have specific forms of divisors) 
My search did not turn any results.

Thank you...

Comment: I think, in general, there is no such form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long search I came to the same conclusion. There is No such form.